# access js-context from emscripten-threads

Tags: emscripten

I like to call some global-context-js-function from a thread (compiled by using emscripten), but the global-Js-context is not accessible (ReferenceError: jsFunc is not defined). I can imagine that the main reason for this problem is that WebWorker (used for threads in emscripten) does not have access to the global-js-context (eg window).

Is there a way to get access to the global-js-context from a cpp-emscripten-thread? Or at least to use some kind of event-bus between threads and the global-js-context? Is there any way to communicate?

Right now, I'm polling from js on a cpp-variable, which is changed by a thread. I hope there is a better way.

Below you find an example of this problem.

Maybe i have overlooked some emscripten functionalities for it?

Thanks,

Benedikt.

```cpp
#include <pthread.h>
#include <emscripten.h>

EM_JS(void, jsFunc, (int msg), {
    // some function in global js context
    myCustomLog(msg);
});


void* perform_work(void*) {
  printf("in thread \n");

  // this call of some global scope js function fails
  // ReferenceError: jsFunc is not defined
  jsFunc(1);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  pthread_t thread;
  printf("in main\n");

  // this call of some global scope js function works fine
  jsFunc(0);

  pthread_create(&thread, NULL, perform_work, NULL);
}
```

build:

```
emcc -o test.html  -s USE_PTHREADS=1  ../main.cpp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way.

```cpp
MAIN_THREAD_ASYNC_EM_ASM('myCustomLog(3);');
```

`myCustomLog(3);` is a function in main Browser Thread

see https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/ccbc3ec51bb905c024e83de7add950dc49345918/system/include/emscripten/em_asm.h#L204-L209